# How can I transform a graphql request with two arguments to one with one argument?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a graphql mutation that looks like this:

```js
mutation ($entityId: ID!, $reviewId: ID!) {
  removeReview (entityId: $entityId, reviewId: $reviewId) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Which delegates to another schema to remove an associated entity

```js
input RemovePostInput {
  id
}

mutation ($input: RemovePostInput) {
  removePost (input: $input) {
     id
  }
}
```

And in my resolver, I'm using `delegateToSchema` but I can't get my transforms right. I'm able to wrap the fieldname, and add my own selectionset as well as the new `input` argument, but I can't get rid of the incoming two arguments.

Is there a built-in transformer to remove arguments, or if not, how can I make a `transformRequest` transformer to convert two arguments into one. If I had one named type transformed to another named type, I would just use a RenameTypes transformer, but the number of arguments is different, which I can't figure out.

```js
delegateToSchema({
  schema: remoteSchema,
  operation: 'mutation',
  fieldName: 'deletePost',
  args: { input: { id: postId } },
  transforms: [
    new WrapQuery(['deletePost'], POST_WITH_REPLIES_SELECTIONSET, (result) => result)
  ],
  context,
  info
});
```